# Get value from selected Node in Treeview

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, treeview

I am dealing with Treeview control and I need to get a clear picture on now can I get the selected node's name from the treeview.  I tried using After_click methods etc etc.

Which class gives the function for the same (CTreeCtrl?). What should I do in the BEGIN MAP and END MAP?

In other words, what event should I map this function to? Is there a click event for the nodes?

Comment: Use `CTreeCtrl::GetItem` (in the `TVITEM` structure, initialize `pszText` and `cchTextMax`, and set the `TVIF_TEXT` mask bit) to get an item's label. I'm not sure what you're asking regarding BEGIN/END MAP.

Comment: I found in some posts that we should add some notify functions between BEGIN/END MAP. Thanks

Comment: The fact that it is urgent is your problem, not ours. Please don't include comments like that. If the problem is important to you, I suggest that you slow down and think a little more. Try to ask a more clear question. Do you want to know how to get the text of the node? Or do you want to know how to be notified of when the user edits it? Two utterly different questions. And yet it's not clear from the title and the body of the question which you want. This is what happens when you write things down in a tearing hurry without thinking hard enough. -1

Comment: please help me to get the name of the selected node at runtime.. Actually sorry for the vague question.. I think the question is much clear now..

Comment: You did not really address my comments. Your question still goes on about message maps. But you you say you just want the item text. The text of an item is retrieved with [`CTreeCtrl::GetItemText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t2ff943.aspx) Have you read any of the documentation yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you were looking for:
Create an event handler for the Tree Control for `TVN_SELCHANGED` notification message.
This will let you code the parts for the click event on nodes.
Use the `GetSelectedItem()` method of the Tree Control to get the label of the selected node.

There is no need to map anything in the `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP/END_MESSAGE_MAP` part for this.